# Loop inside loop React's functional component

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and I've encountered a strange problem when I have a loop inside another loop in react's functional component. From the code below you'll see that I have a loop based on the value of `count` and then there are two other loops within this loop based on the value `index`.

```
{ Object.keys(ticker).length > 0 && <div>
        {Array.from({ length: REVENUE_TYPE.length }).map((_, count) => (
          <div>
            <Card className="mx-3 mb-3" key={ count }>
              <Card.Header>
                {count == 0 && <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
                  Modify Chart0
                </Button>}
                {count == 1 && <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
                  Modify Chart1
                </Button>}
                { productTypes }
                { geo }
                {count} //shows 0 or 1
                <Offcanvas show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                  <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
                    <Offcanvas.Title>Chart Data Selection</Offcanvas.Title>
                  </Offcanvas.Header>
                  <Offcanvas.Body>
                    {count} //show 1 only
                    {count == 0 && Array.from({ length: productTypes.length }).map((_, index) => (
                      <Switch key={index} type={ productTypes[index] }/>
                    ))}
                    {count == 1 && Array.from({ length: geo.length }).map((_, index) => (
                      <Switch key={index} type={ geo[index] }/>
                    ))}
                  </Offcanvas.Body>
                </Offcanvas>
              </Card.Header>
              <Card.Body style={{height:"300px"}}>
              { REVENUE_TYPE[count] != 'store_count' && <LineChart data={ ticker } infoToDisplay={ REVENUE_TYPE[count] } />}
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </div>         
        ))} 
        </div>
      }
```

`count` only goes from 0 to 1, for demonstration purposes I've put two buttons:

```
{count == 0 && <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
      Modify Chart0
</Button>}
{count == 1 && <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
      Modify Chart1
</Button>}
```

As expected, both buttons appear, one showing `Modify Chart0` and the other showing `Modify Chart1`.

Here is where I'm confused, the part where I have the code:

```
<Offcanvas.Body>
    {count}
    {count == 0 && Array.from({ length: productTypes.length }).map((_, index) => (
        <Switch key={index} type={ productTypes[index] }/>
    ))}
    {count == 1 && Array.from({ length: geo.length }).map((_, index) => (
        <Switch key={index} type={ geo[index] }/>
    ))}
</Offcanvas.Body>
```

`count` only ever shows 1, and not 0, as a result only,

```
<Switch key={index} type={ geo[index] }/>
```

get displayed and not:

```
<Switch key={index} type={ productTypes[index] }/>
```

My intuition tells me the outer loop goes from 0 to 1, when `count` is 0, `<Switch key={index} type={ geo[index] }/>` should render and when `count` is 1, `<Switch key={index} type={ productTypes[index] }/>` should render. I must be missing something.

My question is why is `count` only ever `1` inside the `OffCanvans` but shows `0` or `1` outside of it? What should I do to get the correct `Switch` component to render?

Comment: What is the value of `show` before this line when `count = 0` ?
`<Offcanvas show={show} onHide={handleClose}>`

Comment: Not related but why are you doint `Array.from({ length: geo.length }).map((_, index) => (<Switch key={index} type={ geo[index] }/>))}` instead of `geo.map((value, index) => (<Switch key={index} type={value}/>)` (same for productTypes)

Comment: Interesting, I'm not getting any values for ```show``` at that point, I'll investigate

Comment: show is a boolean so maybe you need to do `{String(show)}`

Comment: So it shows ```false``` until I click the button then it becomes ```true```